# Adding List item without user info (anonymously) for authenticated users in SP Online using JS

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, reactjs

We have a SharePoint online site with organization only access.

We have set of users who will be submitting a survey/feedback which needs to be added to list without user info (anonymously) to follow GDPR guideline. This is only for 1 list.

Code base is purely ReactJS based (NOT SPFx) and referred in Content Editor.

Any Pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways to achieve the given scenario.

**Create HTTP triggered Power Automate:**

You can create a flow which will be the HTTP triggered, you can pass the data and in the action to create an entry in SharePoint list, you can use the connection of service account or an admin user. All the entries created and modified will be of the same user whose connection is used.

[Calling Microsoft Flow from your application](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/call-flow-restapi/) is the example of sending an email but that action can be replaced by create an item in SharePoint.

**Custom API:**

You can host your custom APIs in Azure, in which authentication can be done via an App-based context.

**References:**

[Granting access using SharePoint App-Only](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs)

[Controlling app access on a specific SharePoint site collections is now available in Microsoft Graph](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/)

Comment: Yeah, that's how I would do it.  The `Created By` and `Modified By` fields must have *some* value in them.